# Elegant way to get a symmetric Torch Tensor over diagonal

Tags: pytorch

**Is there an elegant way to build a `Torch.Tensor` like this from a given set of values?**

Here is an 3x3 example, but in my application I would have a matrix of any odd-size.

A function call `gen_matrix([a, b, c, d, e, f])` should generate

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [torch.triu_indices()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.triu_indices.html) to achieve this. Note that for a general *N x N* symmetric matrix, there can be atmost *N(N+1)/2* unique elements which are distributed over the matrix.

The `vals` tensor here stores the elements you want to build the symmetric matrix with. You can simply use your set of values in place of `vals`. Only constraint is, it should have *N(N+1)/2* elements in it.

**Short answer**:

```py
N = 5 # your choice goes here
vals = torch.arange(N*(N+1)/2) + 1 # values

A = torch.zeros(N, N)
i, j = torch.triu_indices(N, N)
A[i, j] = vals
A.T[i, j] = vals
```

**Example**:

```py
>>> N = 5
>>> vals = torch.arange(N*(N+1)/2) + 1
 
>>> A = torch.zeros(N, N)
>>> i, j = torch.triu_indices(N, N)
>>> A[i, j] = vals
>>> A.T[i, j] = vals
  
>>> vals
 tensor([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11., 12., 13., 14.,
         15.])
>>> A
 tensor([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
         [ 2.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.],
         [ 3.,  7., 10., 11., 12.],
         [ 4.,  8., 11., 13., 14.],
         [ 5.,  9., 12., 14., 15.]])
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That is exactly what I was looking for. I am just having an issue trying to do it with more dimensions. like: 
`vals = vals.reshape((1, 1, -1));
A = torch.zeros(1, 1, N, N);
A[:, :, i, j] = vals;
A.T[:, :, i, j] = vals; # Colab kernel crashes on this like.`.
I am getting the following log message
`src/tcmalloc.cc:283] Attempt to free invalid pointer 0x7ffcedbf1818`
Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Never mind. Just noticed that it was the `A.T` operation. That changed the shape on the wrong way. I should use `A.transpose(-2, -1)` when having higher dimensions.

Comment: I actually didn't think of tensors having dimensions > 2 while writing the answer as you didn't mention anything in the question. Nice to see it works in higher dimensions too!